# NPE on TextView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        ShimmerTextView mShimmerTextView = (ShimmerTextView) findViewById(R.id.shimmerMotion);
        new Shimmer().start(mShimmerTextView);
    }
```

As seen is the image there are only two layout files in the respective version folders. I am testing on API 22 device and so it should pick the layout from layout-v14 but instead it is inflating the layout-v10 file.

[image]

If I click holding control on the view then android studio opens v14 layout in studio as seen in image below.

[image]
[image]

v10 layout folder does not have that view.

[image]

***Why is my device picking the v10 layout to inflate instead of v14 when my device is running on API22.***

When I click on the TextView it should become a shimmer text and this was working for weeks until now. But today it is throwing NPE.

```
08-20 20:21:21.765  18635-18635/com.ralok.antitheftalarm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.ralok.antitheftalarm, PID: 18635
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.romainpiel.shimmer.ShimmerViewBase.isSetUp()' on a null object reference
                at com.romainpiel.shimmer.Shimmer.start(Shimmer.java:150)
                at com.ralok.view.HomePage.startMotionModeDetection(HomePage.java:650)
                at com.ralok.view.HomePage.onClick(HomePage.java:450)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Have you check the referenced id is the same in xml. It would be better to post that also. There is no need for images. Just post the relevant layout files

Comment: Side-note: you should target SDKs including ICS, i.e. `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: @Raghunandan I have posted a part of the XML layout file. Reference ID's from v-14 are matching in class file. The same ID's are not present in v-10.

Comment: @Simas I have changed it to >=, I missed that initially. Thank you.

Comment: When I create layout-v21 and copy paste the same file from layout-v14, then it works. Why is this happening suddenly from yesterday. It was getting the file from layout-v14 until yesterday.